# How to have a repeating-linear-gradient in Objective C or Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, iphone

I am trying to find a solution to use repeating linear gradient in Objective C/Swift for a iPhone app. For a linear gradient we generally use CAGradientLayer but for repeating linear gradient i couldn't find a solution. I am looking for gradient shown in below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient#Zebra_stripes

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: What OS is this for? iOS? macOS? Other? Show what you have tried so far and clearly explain what issues you are having.

Comment: Those images are not gradients. You don’t want a gradient, you want a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to multiple alternating gradients?

CAGradientLayer has the system's own method, by adding multiple `CGColorRef` settings, you can also set their `locations` (interval), `startPoint` `endPoint` (direction).    [This is the official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer/1462403-colors?language=objc)

**If you want to add 5 pairs of yellow-blue gradients, you should do this:**

```
UIView *cuntomView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 275, 500)];
[self.view addSubview:cuntomView];

CAGradientLayer *gradLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradLayer.frame = cuntomView.bounds;
gradLayer.locations = @[@0,@0.1,@0.2,@0.3,@0.4,@0.5,@0.6,@0.7,@0.8,@0.9,@1];
gradLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor];

[cuntomView.layer addSublayer:gradLayer];
```

[image]

**If you want to change the direction of the gradient, you should add startPoint and endPoint to your code.**

```
UIView *cuntomView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 275, 500)];
[self.view addSubview:cuntomView];

CAGradientLayer *gradLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradLayer.frame = cuntomView.bounds;
gradLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gradLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
gradLayer.locations = @[@0,@0.1,@0.2,@0.3,@0.4,@0.5,@0.6,@0.7,@0.8,@0.9,@1];
gradLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor];

[cuntomView.layer addSublayer:gradLayer];
```

[image]

**If you want to control a specific gradient position, you should set the value in locations. :**

```
UIView *cuntomView = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 275, 500)];
[self.view addSubview:cuntomView];

CAGradientLayer *gradLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradLayer.frame = cuntomView.bounds;
gradLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
gradLayer.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 1);
gradLayer.locations = @[@0,@0.05,@0.1,@0.15,@0.2,@0.25,@0.3,@0.35,@0.8,@0.9,@1];
gradLayer.colors = @[(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor blueColor].CGColor,(__bridge id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor];

[cuntomView.layer addSublayer:gradLayer];
```

[image]